# Convert byte[] to short[]

Tags: c#, arrays, short

Okay, I'm trying to convert a byte[] to a short[], or Int16[].

```
List<Int16[]> lol = new List<Int16[]>();
byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("lolololololololololololoolol");
lol.Add(Convert.ToInt16(b));

MessageBox.Show(Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(lol[0])));
```

That is something that I tried, but obviously, it doesn't work. So how would  I do this?

Comment: 2 things: what did it do instead of working, and could you tell us what is the expected result of the conversion?  Oh, and a third thing: your code is creating a list of arrays of shorts.  Maybe you want `List<Int16>` rather than `List<Int16[]>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert audio bytes - byte\[\] to short\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728865/efficiently-convert-audio-bytes-byte-to-short)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to convert an entire array in one line. It could be done like this:

```
List<Int16[]> lol = new List<Int16[]>();
byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("lolololololololololololoolol");
lol.Add(Array.ConvertAll(b, x => Convert.ToInt16(x)));
```

Comment: This turns each 8 bits into a short. But a short is 16 bits.

Comment: That's right, and essentially it's what was asked for: "trying to convert a byte[] to a short[], or Int16[]".

Comment: Usually what's desired is for two bytes to turn into one short.  Or at least that's much more likely to generate a question, since turning one byte into one short is so easy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through the byte array, and convert each element.

```
List<Int16[]> lol=new List<Int16[]>();
byte [] b=System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("lolololololololololololoolol");
Int16 [] a=new Int16 [b.Length];
for (Int32 i=0;i<a.Length;++i) {

    a[i]=Convert.ToInt16(b[i]);

}
lol.Add(a);
```

Comment: This turns each 8 bits into a short.  But a short is 16 bits.

Comment: I'm well aware.  He never said anything about wanting to merge each set of 2 Bytes into an Int16.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [`BitConverter.ToInt16()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter_methods.aspx), which you'd need to call for each pair of bytes.

Or, use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) to do it all at once (using the machine's native byte order).

Comment: I got it with Buffer.BlockCopy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
        byte[] by = new byte[5];
        short[] sh = new short[5];
        by[0] = 0x1;
        by[1] = 0x2;
        by[2] = 0x3;
        by[3] = 0x4;
        by[4] = 0x5;

        for (int x = 0; x < sh.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            sh[x] = by[x];
            MessageBox.Show(by[x].ToString());
```

That worked for me. Not sure if I am misunderstanding or not.

Comment: This turns each 8 bits into a short. But a short is 16 bits.